# Hover state colour for the "Ask a Question" button in the tour is broken

Tags: bug, design

This happens on Chrome 46:

[image]

Comment: Could not reproduce, Chrome 46.0.2490.86 on Arch Linux. At least, the hover colour showed up not on the "Ask question", but on the "see new questions" button.

Comment: Mh. This is on a mac with retina display.

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu 15.10 with Chromium 45. Hover over the buttons.. (cc @muru)

Comment: @Seth hovered, but only showed up on "See New Questions": http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe6sT.png, http://i.stack.imgur.com/9o5aV.png

Comment: @muru strange. Happens on both of them for me. (slightly older version, different OS).

Comment: Same as muru, only on "See New Questions". Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80  @ Ubuntu GNOME 15.10